# Tomcat Deployment of WAR 404

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-deployment

I am having a strange issue. I have a project running on Tomcat 8 on my local machine just fine. I am using Intellij for development. However when I deploy this same WAR, that is working just fine on my local machine, to the QA Tomcat server it just results in 404s. I have parsed through the logs, and I am fairly certain there are no errors because my app runs some code upon startup and I can see the logging statements for those. I am wondering if it is related to the context path.

I am using Java Config instead of XML. Here is my replacement for web.xml.

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        /**
         * If no active profile is set via -Dspring.profiles.active then the application
         * will default to development mode
         */
        container.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "dev");

        /**
         * create the root Spring application context
         */
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setDisplayName("knowledge-works");
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        /**
         * manage the lifecycle of the root application context
         */
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        /**
         * register and map the dispatcher servlet
         */
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full URL you are trying?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Locally it is localhost:8080/dashboard, on the qa server it is deploying as localhost:8080/knowledge-works/dashboard.

Comment: Instead / as well as of `setDisplayName`, do you not need to call `setNamespace`? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.html#setNamespace-java.lang.String-

Comment: Ohh yea I am using the ip to access QA server 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: setNamespace had no effect, this is really odd issue.